# & appearing as &amp when viewing record

Tags: 2013, list, encoding

I have a dropdown box which has options like `New, O & R, Old`. When I choose the `O & R` option, it appears fine in the list but when I view the record it appears like `O &amp; R`. Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: What type of field is that?

Comment: It is a choice field.

Comment: Is it a Custom form you are using? I tried on SharePoint Online and it is working fine.

Comment: yes it is a custom form I created via sharepoint designer.

Comment: anyone have a idea?